# Margin-left ignored in Chrome on page-load

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have run into following issue. I am displaying a table with data on a page, which is nested in main . Its margin-left isset to 5% (margin-right too) and it has defined width. For some reason when I load the page in Chrome, the left margin is ignored. And here it gets interesting. When I open dev console it gets applied. If I reload the page with console open, it gets broken again. When I turn off any css setting in the console (or basicaly touch anything related to content) it gets fixed again. I am using Unsemantic framework for responsive behavior (only desktop part of it) and I had no trouble with it so far, just this. And since it behaves this strangely, I dont think it has anything to do with the code.

You can see it clearly on this short screencap: http://screencast.com/t/mGotS01iC

Just to be sure, I am posting HTML and CSS for the element:

```
<table class="grid-90 prefix-5 suffix-5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th> UserName </th>
<th> Email </th>
<th> Guid </th>
<th> IsUsingTempPasswd </th>
<th> LastLogin </th>
<th> PasswordChanged </th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Administrator </td>
<td> admin@physter.com </td>
<td>
<div class="table-long">00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000069</div>
</td>
<td class="cell-checkbox">
<input class="check-box" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
</td>
<td> </td>
<td> 26.7.2013 12:11:06 </td>
<td class="actions">
<a href="/User/Edit?guid=00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000069">Edit</a>
|
<a href="/User/Details?guid=00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000069">Details</a>
|
<a href="/User/Delete?guid=00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000069">Delete</a>
|
<a href="/User/ResetPassword?guid=00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000069">Reset Password</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> venca </td>
<td> venca@mail.cz </td>
<td>
<div class="table-long">00000002-0000-0000-0000-00000000006a</div>
</td>
<td class="cell-checkbox">
<input class="check-box" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
</td>
<td> 23.8.2013 12:23:39 </td>
<td> 26.7.2013 12:11:06 </td>
<td class="actions">
<a href="/User/Edit?guid=00000002-0000-0000-0000-00000000006a">Edit</a>
|
<a href="/User/Details?guid=00000002-0000-0000-0000-00000000006a">Details</a>
|
<a href="/User/Delete?guid=00000002-0000-0000-0000-00000000006a">Delete</a>
|
<a href="/User/ResetPassword?guid=00000002-0000-0000-0000-00000000006a">Reset Password</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="7">
<a href="/User/Create">Create New</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is CSS for the element:

```
grid-90 {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
}
.suffix-5 {
    margin-right: 5%;
}
.prefix-5 {
    margin-left: 5%;
}
.grid-5, .mobile-grid-5, .tablet-grid-5, .grid-10, .mobile-grid-10, .tablet-grid-10, .grid-15, .mobile-grid-15, .tablet-grid-15, .grid-20, .mobile-grid-20, .tablet-grid-20, .grid-25, .mobile-grid-25, .tablet-grid-25, .grid-30, .mobile-grid-30, .tablet-grid-30, .grid-35, .mobile-grid-35, .tablet-grid-35, .grid-40, .mobile-grid-40, .tablet-grid-40, .grid-45, .mobile-grid-45, .tablet-grid-45, .grid-50, .mobile-grid-50, .tablet-grid-50, .grid-55, .mobile-grid-55, .tablet-grid-55, .grid-60, .mobile-grid-60, .tablet-grid-60, .grid-65, .mobile-grid-65, .tablet-grid-65, .grid-70, .mobile-grid-70, .tablet-grid-70, .grid-75, .mobile-grid-75, .tablet-grid-75, .grid-80, .mobile-grid-80, .tablet-grid-80, .grid-85, .mobile-grid-85, .tablet-grid-85, .grid-90, .mobile-grid-90, .tablet-grid-90, .grid-95, .mobile-grid-95, .tablet-grid-95, .grid-100, .mobile-grid-100, .tablet-grid-100, .grid-33, .mobile-grid-33, .tablet-grid-33, .grid-66, .mobile-grid-66, .tablet-grid-66 {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
table {
    border: medium none;
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    color: #006666;
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Verdana,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
```

Anybody has an idea? I would be grateful for solution that would allow me keep the framework as it is and do not overwrite its behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing needed was a little "hack" - adding `float:none !important;` to `<table>` elelemnt was enough.

Thanks to Dragos Sandu who put me up to this - removing `float:left` from `grid-90` class was his idea and first step I tried.

Comment: All's well that ends well :)

Answer (score 1):

Width of 90% and the fact that you want the table on center are enough. The edges will be calculated automatically. So your code would look like this:

CSS

```
grid-90 {
    width: 90%; }

.grid-5, .mobile-grid-5, .tablet-grid-5, .grid-10, .mobile-grid-10, .tablet-grid-10, .grid-15, .mobile-grid-15, .tablet-grid-15, .grid-20, .mobile-grid-20, .tablet-grid-20, .grid-25, .mobile-grid-25, .tablet-grid-25, .grid-30, .mobile-grid-30, .tablet-grid-30, .grid-35, .mobile-grid-35, .tablet-grid-35, .grid-40, .mobile-grid-40, .tablet-grid-40, .grid-45, .mobile-grid-45, .tablet-grid-45, .grid-50, .mobile-grid-50, .tablet-grid-50, .grid-55, .mobile-grid-55, .tablet-grid-55, .grid-60, .mobile-grid-60, .tablet-grid-60, .grid-65, .mobile-grid-65, .tablet-grid-65, .grid-70, .mobile-grid-70, .tablet-grid-70, .grid-75, .mobile-grid-75, .tablet-grid-75, .grid-80, .mobile-grid-80, .tablet-grid-80, .grid-85, .mobile-grid-85, .tablet-grid-85, .grid-90, .mobile-grid-90, .tablet-grid-90, .grid-95, .mobile-grid-95, .tablet-grid-95, .grid-100, .mobile-grid-100, .tablet-grid-100, .grid-33, .mobile-grid-33, .tablet-grid-33, .grid-66, .mobile-grid-66, .tablet-grid-66 {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
table {
    border: medium none;
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
    color: #006666;
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Verdana,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
```

In HTML remove the names of the two divisions: `<table class="grid-90">` I hope that helps!

Comment: those "grid" classes are actually from the framework, so this would mean I might screw up design everywhere since I use them all over the place. I will give it a try though...

Comment: Yes, you might be right. I think my solution is not suitable for adaptive design.